# PJSIP via CLI on Raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi, pjsip

I am new to Raspberry and VOIP. I am interested to make a door intercom system using raspberry, as I read most of the post here and those are really helpful,one of the raspberry is acting as server (Asterisk and PBX). I was able to call using sflphonebut that was only for desktop mode and I am interested to call using CLI and for that I installed "PJSIP" as reffered by most of users, but don't have any idea what to do next (I mean how should i start). As it is written after installation I am supposed to try for "pjsua" and "pjsystest" in pjsip-apps/bin, but it doesn't ring any bell for me.
Sorry for my level as beginner but if you don't begin how are you supposed to masters it.

I shall be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i can't explain all of the stuff you need to know, but with [this](http://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/intro_pjsua2.html) Site you should be able to register to you PBX. It's an documentation to the high level API of PJSUA. If you go further on that site they will lead you through the things you have to do to establish a call.

Although this can be very frustrating because there are many error that can appear. There are some python test application under `pjproject/pjsip-apps/src/python/samples`, here you should firstly try to establish a call between two clients to be sure you server is well configured.

Just for info, the dest_uri you have to give in the call.py is like so `sip:ip:port` and you have to change the values in the register.py to your client infos. Then run the register.py in one shell and the call.py in an other shell.

Hopefully i could help you over some barriers, feel free to ask if something was unclear.

Comment: I am able to call from one raspi to other one, that is working perfectly. There is an issue of voice delay for this communication that I have to figure out. May be you can help in that as I tried a lot in media class(from pjsua.py) to adjust it but no solution. My next approach is for video call. I hope I will do that within next week.
If I need your help I will ask you. Thansk a lot for your response, but why so late :( ??

Comment: you could have also just came up to B5.01, we are in the same university :)

Comment: mh to your delay problem i can't say it that specific because there could be many causes for this, maybe it's the network, maybe its the voip server, and maybe it is your program. Try to eliminate some of the "maybe" causes and you will find the problem.